# FSFindFolder for find a file/folder in trash

Tags: objective-c, c, macos-carbon

Got a problem for how to determine file/folder in trash.
There's some solution on Internet, one of those is FSFindFolder.
which can be used something like this:

`FSFindFolder(kUserDomain, kTrashFolderType, true, &trashRef);`

but still don't know how to pass the path of file that I want to determine using this method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last parameter of `FSFindFolder` is a `FSRef`, which can be converted to a `CFURLRef` and to a `NSURL`:

```
FSRef trashRef;
FSFindFolder(kUserDomain, kTrashFolderType, true, &trashRef);
CFURLRef urlRef = CFURLCreateFromFSRef(NULL, &trashRef);
NSURL *trashUrl = CFBridgingRelease(urlRef);
NSString *trashPath = [trashUrl path];
NSLog(@"trash folder: %@", trashPath);
```

(I have omitted the error checking for sake of brevity. I have also assumed that you use automatic reference counting.)

Now you can check if a given file is in the trash folder:

```
NSString *theFile = ...; // your file here
NSString *fileInTrash = [trashPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:theFile];
BOOL isInTrash = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileInTrash];
NSLog(@"is in trash: %d", isInTrash);
```

**NOTE:** On Mac OS X 10.8, `FSFindFolder` is deprecated, and you can use the following code to find the trash folder:

```
NSString *trashPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSTrashDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

Comment: Thanx. finally I understand the flow. by the way, I have one question, is it thrash directory not always in `[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@".Trash"];`

Comment: @arufian: I *think* it was a different path in the first versions of Mac OS X, but I am not sure about that. So these things can change between releases, and it is just safer to use the function instead of a hard-coded path.

Comment: The file may be in external volume(ex:USB memory). In that case, trash directory is not in the home directory but in the volume. You can use `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSTrashDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filename] create:NO error:&error]` to get trash directory related to the file.